# Updating from deprecated response call not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I am updating deprecated response calls but facing a unusual issue whereby the response isn't ended. Normally I would use :

```
 res.send(200, {message: 'Location Updated'});
```

but this is now deprecated. I switched to the new code

```
res.status(200).send(('Location Updated').toString());
```

but this now doesn't return a status or end the query.

The full code I am using

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, update, {new: true})
  .select('-hash')
  .exec(function(err, user) {
    if (err) return res.sendStatus(422);
    if (!user) return res.sendStatus(401);

    //Update User on Map if active
    if(user.workday == true) { 
      socket.send('location_update', user);
    }

    res.send(200, {message: 'Location Updated'}); // Does end query but is deprecated !!!
    //res.status(200).send(('Location Updated').toString()); //Doesnt end query?!?!?!?
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the [res.send](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send) method ends the response, it doesn't exit the function. You'll have to return the response to exit the function and stop the query:

```
return res.status(200).send('Location Updated');
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention I tried this and the same result

Comment: I just tested this and it's working. Can you post the full source code for the app.js?